# Prevent 'Run-time error '7' out of memory' error in Excel when using macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I keep getting this error whenever I run a macro in my excel file. Is there any way I can prevent this? My code is below. Debugging highlights the following line as the issue:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
```

My macro:

```
Private Sub Save()

Dim sh As Worksheet

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Copy 'Create new workbook with Sheets("Report"(2)) as only sheet.
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Set the new sheet to a variable. New workbook is now active workbook.
sh.Name = sh.Range("B9") & "_" & Format(Date, "mmyyyy") 'Rename the new sheet to B9 value + date.
With sh.UsedRange.Cells
    .Value = .Value 'eliminate all formulas
    .Validation.Delete 'remove all validation
    .FormatConditions.Delete 'remove all conditional formatting
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete

    lrow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'select rows from bottom up to last containing data in column I
    Rows(lrow + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete 'delete rows with no data in column I
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    .Range("A410:XFD1048576").Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delete all cells outwith report range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim counter
    Dim nameCount

    nameCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
    counter = nameCount
    Do While counter > 0
    ActiveWorkbook.Names(counter).Delete
    counter = counter - 1
    Loop 'remove named ranges from workbook

End With
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\Marko\Report\" & sh.Name & ".xlsx" 'Save new workbook using same name as new sheet.
ActiveWorkbook.Close False 'Close the new workbook.
MsgBox ("Export complete. Choose the next ADP in cell B9 and click 'Calculate'.") 'Display message box to inform user that report has been saved.

End Sub
```

Not sure how to make this more efficient or to prevent this error.

Comment: Are there any shapes in the workbook?

Comment: Yes, 3 form control buttons.

Comment: form control buttons are not shapes. I think it gives this error because there are no shapes.